# Matched grouped - What is the difference between \1 on Search and \1 on Replace

Tags: regex

I've seen very often 2 cases of match groups for `\1`, for example:

- Search: `(?)(\w+d+).*\1`
- Replace: `Leave Empty`

and

- Search: `(?)(\w+d+).*`
- Replace: `\1`

In which cases I can use `\1` on search, and in which cases I can use `\1` on replace?

Comment: `\1` means the first matched group inside parentheses (..), the cases is about your requirements.

Comment: Actually, the question is too broad. What are you asking about?They all  are backreferences. Use in-pattern backreferences when you need to match the same text as is already captured into the corresponding group, and use a replacement backreference when you need to restore part of the match during a regex replacement operation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

?? What do you mean with "what's the difference". There is no difference. Both are referencing the first capturing group. But you do not use them in the same way.

For example:
`(\d+)\.\1` means: "match some numbers `(\d+)` followed by a `.` and the followed by the same numbers `\1`"

**example** `123.123` matches

`(\d+)\.` replace by `\1` means: "replace some numbers followed by a `.` with only the numbers"

**example** `123.` is replaced to `123`

Comment: yes, now I understand. Thanks a lot ! Good answer !

Answer (score 0):

`\1` is a back-reference to the capture group number one, it's placed **inside** the regex. If you want to put a reference to the capture group in the replacement you have to use `$1` or `\1` depending on the regex implementation you use.

Comment: *you have to use `$1`*  - that depends on regex flavor.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew yes, for example ruby uses \1